# How to calculate Hyperledger Besu QBFT Ethereum block hash?

Tags: ethereum, hyperledger, hyperledger-besu

in my network using Hyperledger Besu QBFT

so connect my DAPP and brought the 123rd block and get Blockhead information

this is 123rd block header

{"number":"0x7b","hash":"0x4b689e309026023a19ec160d0657666e1c0fb5b34fce3d08c6b8423540c0b87f","parentHash":"0x6a58d87d29511e0e27b58c25916755283548f05d17334d1d8d90a5b777e2cb0b","nonce":"0x0000000000000000","sha3Uncles":"0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347","logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","transactionsRoot":"0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421","stateRoot":"0xcde4979f7654eb05ba7632d19513c344844ea05560e8153ade9521a87b829f55","receiptsRoot":"0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421","miner":"0xd73bc29c7403e80b59d89b119de11523d2349478","mixHash":"0x63746963616c2062797a616e74696e65206661756c7420746f6c6572616e6365","difficulty":"0x1","totalDifficulty":"0x7c","extraData":"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","size":"0x34a","gasLimit":"0x1fffffffffffff","gasUsed":"0x0","timestamp":"0x65003252","transactions":[],"uncles":[],"baseFeePerGas":"0x0"}

and i want check my blockhash is right so using this test

https://github.com/hyperledger/besu/blob/eef40bd530d8939b56f67c990a7cdf536b7521a7/consensus/clique/src/test/java/org/hyperledger/besu/consensus/clique/CliqueBlockHashingTest.java

and

https://github.com/hyperledger/besu/blob/eef40bd530d8939b56f67c990a7cdf536b7521a7/consensus/ibft/src/test/java/org/hyperledger/besu/consensus/ibft/BftBlockHashingTest.java

i'm insert correct data and build, hash... but blockhash is not match between them

so confuse... How can I calculate those things?

https://github.com/hyperledger/besu/blob/eef40bd530d8939b56f67c990a7cdf536b7521a7/consensus/clique/src/test/java/org/hyperledger/besu/consensus/clique/CliqueBlockHashingTest.java

and

https://github.com/hyperledger/besu/blob/eef40bd530d8939b56f67c990a7cdf536b7521a7/consensus/ibft/src/test/java/org/hyperledger/besu/consensus/ibft/BftBlockHashingTest.java